# How to map a MySQL JSON column to a Java entity property using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, jpa

I have a MySQL column declared as type **JSON** and I have problems to map it with JPA/Hibernate. I'm using Spring Boot on back-end.

Here is small part of my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table_name")
public class MyCustomEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "json_value")
private JSONArray jsonValue;
```

The program returns me an error and tells me that I can't map the column.

In mysql table the column is defined as:

```
json_value JSON NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Try use **columnDefinition = "json"** :

@Column(name = "json_value", columnDefinition = "json")

Comment: Please, share exception you received.

Comment: Problem can be JSONArray type, because everything is working fine if I put String instead.

Comment: Exception: Could not determine type for: org.json.JSONArray, at table: some_table_name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I prefer to do this way:

- Creating converter (attribute converter) from Map to String and vice versa.
- Using Map to map mysql JSON column type in domain (entity) class

The code is bellow.

> JsonToMapConverted.java

```
@Converter
public class JsonToMapConverter 
                    implements AttributeConverter<String, Map<String, Object>> 
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonToMapConverter.class);

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, Object> convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute)
    {
        if (attribute == null) {
           return new HashMap<>();
        }
        try
        {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.readValue(attribute, HashMap.class);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Convert error while trying to convert string(JSON) to map data structure.");
        }
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(Map<String, Object> dbData)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dbData);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error("Could not convert map to json string.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> Part of domain (entity-mapping) class

```
...

@Column(name = "meta_data", columnDefinition = "json")
@Convert(attributeName = "data", converter = JsonToMapConverter.class)
private Map<String, Object> metaData = new HashMap<>();

...
```

This solution perfectly works for me.

Comment: hi, i get this error . `Unexpected error occurred: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter`

Comment: @Heril Same here

Comment: You mixed up in the definition of the convertor. It should implement `AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String>`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I change the database data type to String then it works.

Comment: What will be the data type in DTO.

Comment: what is the use of `attributeName = "data"` here?

Comment: Will this work for eclipselink as well? I'm using the org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider and my jar files are eclipselink.jar and  javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar.

Comment: The converter causes issues for me when persisting entities. I had to go with the UserType approach.

Comment: @Will Udstrand What do you mean by UserType approach?

Answer (score 25):

> You don’t have to create all these types manually. You can simply get
> them via Maven Central using the following dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63</artifactId>
>     <version>${hypersistence-utils.version}</version> 
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> For more info, check out the [Hibernate Types open-source project](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-types-open-source-project-is-born/).

Now, to explain how it all works.

Assuming you have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;
 
    @Type(JsonType.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String properties;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice two things in the code snippet above:

- the `@Type` is used to define a new custom Hibernate Type, `json` which is handled by the [`JsonType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/)
- the `properties` attribute has a `json` column type, and it's mapped as a `String`

That's it!

Now, if you save an entity:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setIsbn("978-9730228236");
book.setProperties(
    "{" +
    "   \"title\": \"High-Performance Java Persistence\"," +
    "   \"author\": \"Vlad Mihalcea\"," +
    "   \"publisher\": \"Amazon\"," +
    "   \"price\": 44.99" +
    "}"
);
 
entityManager.persist(book);
```

Hibernate is going to generate the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO
    book 
(
    isbn, 
    properties, 
    id
) 
VALUES
(
    '978-9730228236', 
    '{"title":"High-Performance Java Persistence","author":"Vlad Mihalcea","publisher":"Amazon","price":44.99}',  
    1
)
```

And you can also load it back and modify it:

```
Book book = entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .bySimpleNaturalId(Book.class)
    .load("978-9730228236");
     
book.setProperties(
    "{" +
    "   \"title\": \"High-Performance Java Persistence\"," +
    "   \"author\": \"Vlad Mihalcea\"," +
    "   \"publisher\": \"Amazon\"," +
    "   \"price\": 44.99," +
    "   \"url\": \"https://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Java-Persistence-Vlad-Mihalcea/dp/973022823X/\"" +
    "}"
);
```

Hibernate taking caare of the `UPDATE` statement for you:

```
SELECT  b.id AS id1_0_
FROM    book b
WHERE   b.isbn = '978-9730228236'
 
SELECT  b.id AS id1_0_0_ ,
        b.isbn AS isbn2_0_0_ ,
        b.properties AS properti3_0_0_
FROM    book b
WHERE   b.id = 1    
 
UPDATE
    book 
SET
    properties = '{"title":"High-Performance Java Persistence","author":"Vlad Mihalcea","publisher":"Amazon","price":44.99,"url":"https://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Java-Persistence-Vlad-Mihalcea/dp/973022823X/"}'
WHERE
    id = 1
```

All code is available on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils).

Comment: Breaks my H2 unit tests: `JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "JSON";`

Comment: @TiggerToo, Of course, it breaks your H2 tests. MySQL functions and features are meant to be tested on MySQL, not H2. Unless you are using H2 in production, which is highly unlikely, then, there is no reason why you'd want to test your data access layer against a different DB engine than the one you are using in production.

Comment: I believe it was you I said this to in another question, but yes, there is a very good reason to use a different DB engine, and it's called unit tests.

Comment: Testing a database is called integration testing. Unit testing is for units, like when you test a method of a POJO or a Service with Mocks.

Comment: @VladMihalcea when reading JSON data from DB, I get special characters for slovenian letters. My DB encoding is utf8, utf8_slovenian_ci. Check this question please for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64246519/mysql-json-data-type-jpa-encoding-issue

Comment: On [your site](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) you have an example with     `@Type(type = "json") @Column(columnDefinition = "json")` on top of an `Location` and `Ticket` classes (not just `String`). Is there a specific reason why your example here uses a `String` property and not a Pojo?

Comment: It works with both String, DTOs, Map or other entity attributes

Comment: @VladMihalcea, I'm getting `Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.` Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan In the GitHub repository of the project, you'll find plenty of tests that show you how to use it. Compare those to your code and see where they differ.

Comment: @TiggerToo you can use TestContainers(https://www.testcontainers.org/) if you are writing Integration tests.
VladMihalcea thanks for the interesting answer.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Is there any solution to add inner fields in JOSN column to `Where` clause of a select query?

Comment: @AliSohrabi You need to use a native SQL with the DB-specific syntax to access inner JSON attributes for reading or writing them.

Comment: @VladMIhalcea The annotation at class level TypeDef, is it necessary? Because I have a table with many columns, only one of them is the json string, I do not want to make mysql think that all the class is a Json

Comment: The `@TypeDef` annotation is global and allows you to define an alias you'd reference later at the property level. Without it, you'd have to use the String-based fully-qualified class name on each `@Type` you add to an entity property.

Comment: @VladMihalcea hey I see that in hibernate 6.1.6 this annotation TypeDef got removed, can you pls show example how to call in the Type annotation with fully qualified class JsonType? I was trying but I think it changed alot, what should I do for it to keep working with the JsonType? Think the Type annotation also changed at field level (column)

Comment: You can find lots of examples for Hibernate 6 here https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/tree/master/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/type/json

Answer (score 10):

For anyone can't make @J. Wang answer work :

Try add this dependency(it's for hibernate 5.1 and 5.0, other version check [here](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types))

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And add this line to the entity

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
```

So full version of the entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table_name")
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
public class MyCustomEntity implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @Type( type = "json" )
   @Column( columnDefinition = "json" )
   private List<String> jsonValue;
}
```

I test the code with spring boot 1.5.9 and hibernate-types-5 1.2.0 .

Comment: This is also a good solution, using hibernate types but I think maybe is better to use attribute converter and map. Check out my answer bellow.

Answer (score 6):

If the values inside your json array are simple strings you can do this:

```
@Type( type = "json" )
@Column( columnDefinition = "json" )
private String[] jsonValue;
```

Comment: The `@Type` is a `org.hibernate.annotations.Type`

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'type'

Answer (score 6):

[Heril Muratovic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52748015/4644462) is good, but I think the `JsonToMapConverter` should implement `AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String>`, not `AttributeConverter<String, Map<String, Object>>`. Here is the code that works for me

```java
@Slf4j
@Converter
public class JsonToMapConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String> {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.readValue(attribute, HashMap.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Convert error while trying to convert string(JSON) to map data structure.", e);
        }
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, Object> dbData) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dbData);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Could not convert map to json string.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error after using the above class. My problem is - My postgres table has a JSON column, need to map them in aggEntity class. So used the above class but getting error.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, the following variation/combination of the above suggestions worked for me:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_menu")
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class)
data class ProductMenu(

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(name = "menu_json", columnDefinition = "json")
    @Convert(attributeName = "menuJson", converter = JsonToMapConverter::class)
    val menuJson: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()

) : Serializable



import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.io.IOException
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter

class JsonToMapConverter : AttributeConverter<String, HashMap<String, Any>> {

    companion object {
        private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonToMapConverter::class.java)
    }

    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: String?): HashMap<String, Any> {
        if(attribute == null) {
            return HashMap()
        }
        try {
            val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return objectMapper.readValue(attribute, HashMap::class.java) as HashMap<String, Any>
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            LOGGER.error("Convert error while trying to convert string(JSON) to map data structure.")
        }
        return HashMap()
    }

    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: HashMap<String, Any>?): String? {
        return try {
            val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
            objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dbData)
        } catch (e: JsonProcessingException) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not convert map to json string.")
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone can't make @J. Wang answer work :

Try add this dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Creating converter

> JSONObjectConverter.java

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class JSONObjectConverter implements AttributeConverter<JSONObject, String> {

 private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(JSONArrayConverter.class);

 @Override
 public String convertToDatabaseColumn(JSONObject obj)
 {
    String data = null;
    try
    {
        data = obj.toString();
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("JSON writing error", e);
    }

    return data;
 }

 @Override
 public JSONObject convertToEntityAttribute(String data)
 {
    JSONObject obj = null;

    try
    {
        Object temp = JSONValue.parse(data);
        obj = (JSONObject) temp ;
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("JSON reading error", e);
    }

    return obj;
 }
}
```

> Part of domain (entity-mapping) class

```
...

@Lob
@Column(name = "pano_data", columnDefinition = "JSON", nullable = true)
@Convert(converter = JSONObjectConverter.class)
private JSONObject panoData;

...
```

This solution perfectly works for me.