# MySQL JSON Data Type / JPA Encoding issue

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, jpa, objectmapper

I have an issue with JSON data type in MySQL. In that column I'm writing values that are based on  slovenian letters.

Here is an example that is written using ObjectMapper:

```
{ "formState": [{"label": "Zaduženi", "value": "Test 1"}, {"label": "Tip", "value": "Fizičko"}] }
```

I'm using JPA to fetch data from MySQL database and in the payload I'm getting something like this:

```
{ "formState": [{"label": "ZaduÅ¾eni", "value": "Test 1"}] }
```

The Java data type that I'm using to represent this JSON is Map (HashMap).

Data source url is: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false`

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Somewhere the UTF8 is being treated as ASCII. You have to check and make sure that your database, table and fields are all using the `utf8mb4` character set. This specific way of mangling that letter doesn't appear to be on the Java side.

Comment: @coladict my database is created by this command: CREATE DATABASE test_db CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci;

Comment: @coladict changing character set from utf8 to utf8mb4 on specific table is not helping.

Comment: Then you have to check with the console if it is stored properly or mangled. This will help you narrow down the source of the problem. The next thing I would try after that is to debug the application. Put a breakpoint within the JDBC driver on `setString(int, String)`, `getString(int)` the execute function and disable them, then put one at the query in your code, then enable the ones in the driver. You should see during the execution what is being done with the variable at which phase.

Comment: @coladict when I change JSON to TEXT it's working perfectly. But I need that column to be JSON type.

Comment: I tested your settings and data, including the encoding, and it all works on my end. Could be I'm using newer versions of something where the bug is fixed. My tested versions are `hibernate-core:5.2.0.Final`, `mysql-connector-java:8.0.22` and the server is version `8.0.20`.

Comment: @coladict I'm using MySQL 5.7.24

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue in the Hibernate Types framework. Try to replicate it using any of the existing test cases and send me a Pull Request so that I could find the problem.