# How do I PUT and GET JSON object of ANY format in a Spring Boot REST API using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, rest

I need to be able to PUT a JSON data from POSTMAN, with no fixed format, store it in database(in MYSQL preferably with datatype: JSON) and then send a GET request to get the same value back. The data can be uniquely identified by an id that I'll be sending as a path variable.

I cannot define an entity class as the JSON will have no fixed format. How do I proceed?

```
  @PutMapping("/sample/{sampleNo}")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> addSampleData(
      @ApiParam("Sampleto PUT") @PathVariable Long sampleNo, @RequestBody String sampleBody) {
    if (sampleBody!= null) {
      sampleService.save(new Sample(sampleNo, sampleBody));
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }
```

Not sure how to proceed with the "save" functionality so that the data is stored as a JSON object, because even if I've used datatype JSON n mySQL, GET returns a string with "\".

```
{
   "sampleNo": 1,
   "sampleData": "{\"sample\": \"test\", \"sampleNo\": \"20\"}"
}
```

Example: **PUT request body**

```
{
    "field1": "test",
    "field2": 20
}
```

**GET response body expected**

```
{
    "field1": "test",
    "field2": 20
}
```

**P.S: I don't need to process the data, so it doesn't matter how I store it, I just need to be able to GET it back in the same format(JSON) it arrived(in the PUT req).**

Comment: You can use ObjectMapper and convert your result in Map<Key,Value> using this before send response.

Comment: Like this,
``String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);``

Answer (score 0):

`sampleData` is returned as JSON `String`, so it is reasonable to include escape sequence `\"`:

This is a valid JSON `String`:

```
String json = "{\"sample\": \"test\", \"sampleNo\": \"20\"}";
```

This does not compile:

```
String invalidJson = "{"sample": "test", "sampleNo": "20"}";
```

**Solution:**

In order to have the expected response, you have to map your MySQL JSON column into an `Object`.

There are several ways to achieve this, take a look at a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52748015/8909235). It maps JSON column into a `Map<String, Object>`.