# JPA JSON column access via Jackson Eclipselink & Mysql

Tags: mysql, json, jpa, jackson, eclipselink

I'm trying to use a JPA entity to access a JSON column in mysql with my current eclipse link provider:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

I am aware of this but I do not believe I am using hibernate.
[How to map a MySQL JSON column to a Java entity property using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308167/how-to-map-a-mysql-json-column-to-a-java-entity-property-using-jpa-and-hibernate)

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [IntellectPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7347] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The class [filtec.db.TestCriteria] specifies type level convert metadata without specifying an attribute name for each. An attribute name must be provided for all type level convert metadata to ensure the correct application to a super class attribute.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at filtec.db.EM.getEntityManager(EM.java:50)
```

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TestCriteria")
@Convert(converter=JpaConverterJson.class)
public class TestCriteria implements Serializable {

    /** Auto generated Serial ID by Eclipse */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3680147569249120166L;

    /** TRACE log. */
    protected static final Logger TRACE = Logger.getLogger(TestCriteria.class.getName());
    
    /** The container type ID. */
    @Id
    @Column(name="ContainerTypeId", unique=true)
    private int containerTypeId;
    
    /** The JSON document containing the sample criteria array. */
    @Column(name="SampleCriteriaMap")
    @Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
    private Map<String, Object> sampleCriteriaMap;
```

and my converter class:

```
@Converter
public class JpaConverterJson implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {
    
    /** TRACE log. */
    protected static final Logger TRACE = Logger.getLogger(JpaConverterJson.class.getName());
    
    /** single instance as we don't expect much multi-threading. */
    private final static ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object meta) {
        try {
            return OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(meta);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            return null;
            // or throw an error
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(dbData, Object.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            TRACE.severe("Unexpected IOEx decoding json from database: " + dbData);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise on what I've not configured correctly?

Comment: Why do you have @Convert on the entity class? This is what the error is complaining about, as it doesn't know which property you want to run this converter on - just remove it.  See the examples here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html

Comment: @Chris that was careless of me, thank you for the spot!